# My custom Jinja template filter will not register or work?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I've created a custom filter but my Flask server is getting an internal error.

```
@app.template_filter('doSomething')
def doSomething(input):
    print(input)
    return input
```

HTML

```
<p>{{ doSomething('Test') }}</p>
```

Error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'doSomething' is undefined
```

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/

Comment: @AndrewAllen I read it, it's literally where I'm having the issue. As you can see my example matches the first example they give. I even copied their example into my code and I still get the same error for their reverse filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, trial and error, this is the only one that seems to work for me:

```
def doSomething(input):
    print(input)
    return input

app.jinja_env.globals.update(doSomething=doSomething)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/) it says :
`doSomethingWith({{ user.username|tojson|safe }});` which means that the `user.username` object will be json serialised and then passed to the `doSomethingWith` which is a JavaScript function;
not like `{{doSomethingWith(user.username|tojson|safe);}}` you used in your example which looks like you are trying to explicitly  call a python function from the template, so try this and if you still have any troubles tell us more about what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make this answer a bit useful while also addressing the question, I'll show a custom filter function for which I had a need.   You can use the .app_template_filter() decorator method on your Flask app to effectively "register" the new template filter function.   Once it's registered you can use it on any template within the context of your app or blueprint.

If you're using blueprints, in your controller you'd do something like this:

```
@some_blueprint.app_template_filter()
def utcToStrFilter(someUTCFloat):
    try:
        shiftedDateStr = datetime.strftime(datetime.fromtimestamp(someUTCFloat), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        return shiftedDateStr    
    except:
        return ""
```

If you're not using blueprints then your decorator would be:
`@app.app_template_filter()`
or
`@current_app.app_template_filter()`

In any case, then in your template you just use it like a regular jinja filter:

```
{{ something.fileSavetimeUTC | utcToStrFilter }}
```

The key thing is to make the app aware of the function, which is what `.app_template_filter()` is for.